# ANY operator with while loop in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if any of the values in table is equal to 0 and if it is, then wait for a couple of seconds.

Here is what i tried:

```
while(ANY(select CheckIfDone from #CheckValTable )) = 0
 begin
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:3';
 end
```

But I get syntax error with this at `ANY` and `=` .How do I use this query in while loop ?

Comment: what is dbms? sql server / oracle / my sql?

Comment: I am using sql-server.

Answer (score 4):

The grammar for [`ANY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx) is

```
scalar_expression { = | < > | ! = | > | > = | ! > | < | < = | ! < } 
     { SOME | ANY } ( subquery )
```

So the syntax would need to be

```
WHILE( 0 = ANY (SELECT CheckIfDone
                FROM   #CheckValTable) )
  BEGIN
      WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:3';
  END
```

Or `= ANY` is `IN` so you could also write

```
WHILE( 0 IN (SELECT CheckIfDone
             FROM   #CheckValTable) )
  BEGIN
      WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:3';
  END
```

But I would probably use `EXISTS` for clarity

```
WHILE( EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   #CheckValTable
              WHERE  CheckIfDone = 0) )
  BEGIN
      WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:3';
  END
```

But the condition can never change with the code you have shown anyway as other connections can't access the temp table.